# open chrome tab with proxy using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

```
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME 
Proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
driver = webdriver.chrome('tmp/chromedriver', desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")`
```

I'm trying to open a chrome tab with proxy (no authentication needed) but I got this error:

> add_to_capabilities() missing 1 required positional argument: 'capabilities' error

Answer (score 0):

Try following code as EX:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

proxy_url = "127.0.0.1:9009"
proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': proxy_url,
    'sslProxy': proxy_url,
    'noProxy': ''})

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get("http://example.org")
```